# Matching two single quotes or double quote

Tags: regex

I have the following strings. It is LatLongs in degrees, minutes and seconds format,
and can be entered as follows:

```
Option1: 25º 23" 40.6' or
Option2: 25º 23'' 40.6' or
Option3: 25 23 40.6
```

With one regx i would like to match both strings, the problem for me is matching the "(double quote) AND ' '(two single quotes).
I have the following so far.

```
^[+|-]?[0-9]{1,2}[\º| ][ ]?[0-9]{1,2}[\"|'{2}| ]
```

I am building and testing the regx in the terminal on lunix (Ubuntu).
 From the output i get in the terminal its matches the "(double quote) but only ONE of the ' '(two single quotes).
How can i change the regx to match the "(double quote) and ' '(two single quotes), in one expression?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Degrees can go to >99, why are you limiting them to two digits?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this pattern:

```
([+-]?\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?.)\s*(\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?[\S]*)\s*(\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?'?)
```

It is independent of any special character including support of up-to 2 digits, along with the resolution of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex has problems. For example, `[\"|'{2}| ]` matches a single `"`, `|`, `'`, `{`, `2`, `}` or . Try the following:

```
^([+-]?\d+)º? ?\b(\d+)\b(?:''|\")? ?([\d.]+)'?$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               # Start of string
([+-]?\d+)      # Match an integer
º?[ ]?          # Match a degree and/or a space (both optional)
\b(\d+)\b       # Match a positive integer (entire number)
(?:''|\")?[ ]?  # Match quotes and/or space (all optional)
([\d.]+)        # Match a floating point number
'?              # Match an optional single quote
$               # End of string
```

Comment: This regex allows 12.12.12.12....12. seconds. Change final term to `\\d\\d?(\\.\\d+)?` - standard regex for decimal

Comment: @Bohemian: Yes, this regex is not meant to validate input. If it was, it would have to check for valid degree/minute/second ranges, too. This doesn't appear to be the OP's intention which is why it's not mine, either.

Comment: Fair enough, but you can go the extra mile and make it tighter; one step closer to validation, which it is likely to end up as sooner or later. **Congrats 100K!**

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want to have with the Regex above is

```
^[+|-]?[0-9]{1,2}º? ?[0-9]{1,2}(\"|'{2})? ?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]'?
```

Although this also matches weird things like

```
25 23'' 40.6
```

Your Regex uses custom character classes (the sections in `[` and `]`) which only can match one single character. You can group together multiple characters by `(` and `)` and make these groups optional with a `?`.